# Symfony2 generate controller inside custom folder

Tags: php, symfony, command-line

Symfony2 has a command for generating controllers

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_controller.html

Command's default behavior is to generate the given controller inside `controller` folder within the bundle.

Is it possible to customize the folder where the controller will be generated ( `controller/backend` for example ) ?

Comment: You would better have separate bundles for frontend and backend.

Comment: I don't think that you can add the subfolder in the command. Moreover I don't think it's a good way to add a subdirectory in the `YourBundle\Controller`. By the way, may you want create **your own** `generate:controller`. Have a look at [How to create a basic command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html)

Comment: @moonwave99 could you explain why it's better to separate them please ?

Comment: @zizoujab because they have different purposes and they can be [re]used separately. Of course it is a matter of taste ^^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get all the available options of this command with the help command:

```
php app/console help generate:controller
```

No you can't with the current task, but you could extend the `GenerateControllerCommand` to add custom options. Check out its `generate` function:

```
// GenerateControllerCommand.php
public function generate(BundleInterface $bundle, $controller, $routeFormat, $templateFormat, array $actions = array())
{
    ...
    $controllerFile = $dir.'/Controller/'.$controller.'Controller.php';
    ...
    $this->renderFile('controller/Controller.php.twig', $controllerFile, $parameters);
    ...
}
```

Comment: That will not answer the question... The link provided by the OP already list the options.

Comment: @Debflav Added details.

Comment: I'll try to add it and report back

Answer (score 3):

You can try: "php bin/console make:controller Directory\\ControllerName"

Comment: Works in symfony 5.1 php 7.4